# SOIL: ошибка сегментации

Tags: c++, opengl, текстура

Добрый вечер! Я использую библиотеку SOIL чтобы загружать текстуры. Когда я загружаю текстуру после создания окна, все идет нормально. Но когда я делаю это перед созданием окна, программа вылетает:

> Ошибка сегментации

Вот как я загружаю текстуру:

```
texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(path, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, 
SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB);
```

Как избежать ошибки?

Comment: Запустите программу в дебаггере и покажите callstack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее вероятно, что при работе с SOIL у Вас не определен флаг

```
#define SOIL_CHECK_FOR_GL_ERRORS
```

Что не позволяет Вам узнать о том, что [контекст OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)) не создан. Из-за этого функция glGenTextures в недрах библиотеки SOIL может генерировать ошибку сегментации.

Чтобы избежать этого, есть несколько путей:

1. Создавать окно и контекст к нему строго до загрузки ресурсов, при необходимости создавать окно как невидимое и показывать потом, когда в этом появится нужда.
2. Используйте функцию SOIL_load_image, чтобы загрузить изображение в массив байтов, представляющих пиксели, а потом, когда контекст будет создан, воспользуйтесь функцией [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml):

   ```
   GLuint tex = -1;
   glGenTextures(1,&tex);
   glBindTexture(tex,GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,MyImageWidth,MyImageHeight,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,MyImageBytes);
   ```

Второй вариант - это то, что внутри себя делает библиотека SOIL.

Answer (score 0):

Как и было указано выше что из за не созданного контекста OpenGL текстуру создать невозможно. Если вам не текстура нужна а масив точек, то есть просто изображение используйте.

```
     int width, height, nrComponents;



    unsigned char *data = SOIL_load_image(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);

Если текстуру как код ниже, то  после привязке контекста .

GLuint CreateTexture(unsigned char *data, int width, int height, int nrComponents,GLint paramMin = GL_NEAREST, GLint paramMag = GL_NEAREST)
{
    GLuint textureID = 0;
    if (data) //Если не пусто
    {
        //Количество цветов на пиксель
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;
        else
            format = GL_R;


//Генерировать место для текстуры и получить идентификатор
        glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
//Указать что не явные команды будут применимы к этой текстуре
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);



        //задаем алгоритм отрисовки за границами текстури 
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

        //Задаем сглаживание четко иле сглажено если не верно указать то в скай боксе будут видны полоски  
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, paramMin );
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, paramMag);


        //Теперь передаем не посредственно картинку для генерации текстуры 
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        


    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture data failed"<< std::endl;
    }

    return textureID;
}


//Загрузка изображения и генерация текстуры
GLuint loadTexture(char const * path)
{
    GLuint textureID = 0;

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    //Загрузить картинку
    unsigned char *data = SOIL_load_image(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        //Теперь генерируем текстуру из изображения 
        textureID = CreateTexture(data, width, height, nrComponents);
        SOIL_free_image_data(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        SOIL_free_image_data(data);
    }

    return textureID; //Результат, Кстати Крым Это Украина
}
```